# get first elements from array using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

```js
let array =
[[`animal`,`carnivours`],
 [`cow`,`milk`],
 [`plant`,`small`],
 [`fish`,`tank`]]
 
 console.log(array[0]);
```

as I know if I want to fetch first value from array I have to use array[0] to get all the first name from the array but here I am getting first array from array list as my

expected value is like this

```
animal
cow
plant
fish
```

any simplest way to fetch all the first name from the list like this `array[0]` or somewhat like this ?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+get+first+column+of+array) of [Get column from a two dimensional array](/q/7848004/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with the first elements of each inner array.

```js
let array =
[[`animal`,`carnivours`],
 [`cow`,`milk`],
 [`plant`,`small`],
 [`fish`,`tank`]];
let res = array.map(x => x[0]);
console.log(res);
// or
console.log(array.map(([f]) => f));
```

Comment: thank you as i was already knowing this method but trying to minimize the code i guess i have to go with method :) but thank you

Comment: array.map(x => x[0]); is not very much code!

Answer (score 0):

You probably customize a `column` function that returns the ith column of the array:

```js
Array.prototype.column = function(i) {
  try { 
    return this.map( x => x[i]);
  } catch (e) {
    // catch error: out of index or null array ....
    console.log(e);
  }
}

let array =
[[`animal`,`carnivours`],
 [`cow`,`milk`],
 [`plant`,`small`],
 [`fish`,`tank`]];
  
console.log(array.column(0))
console.log(array.column(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let array =
[[`animal`,`carnivours`],
 [`cow`,`milk`],
 [`plant`,`small`],
 [`fish`,`tank`]]
 
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i][0]);
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/XrUKcnlLZQ

Comment: Why would you ever do this, rather than the map function!!??